# Why does Stack Overflow Jobs show no results when logged in?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I'm **logged in** and when I open https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-paris here's what I see (only five featured results):

[image]

While when I **log out** I see 79 results:

[image]

I'm not sure if this some sort of 'feature' and maybe there is some kind of setting in my profile that prevents showing all the other positions.

Comment: Can you try and re-save your current location in your profile?

Comment: @DeanWard re-saved, still only 5 results

Comment: Your dev story is set to a location that isn't Paris. That overrides your profile location for jobs; you can sync the two by checking the sync checkbox when you update your story.

Comment: Thank you @DeanWard found the checkbox in `Job Match Preferences` it's called `always include your current location`. Unchecking it did the job. though as far as I understand it was supposed only supposed to pre-populate job search filter with location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Because you have a home location in your match preferences, your IP location was being ignored. We now always take your IP location into consideration to determine which jobs are visible.

Thanks for your report!

Comment: I think this feature is no longer available beause its been a long while, since I have seen jobs opportunity pop ups in page.

Answer (score 1):

Unticking `Always include your current location` in `Profile -> Edit Profile & settings -> JobMatch preferences` did the trick:

[image]

Comment: There was a bug which is now fixed (see my answer). Ticking the box should not restrict the number of jobs you see in Paris anymore.